# Codeigniter url displaying method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a basic login form with validation containing only that the fields are not empty.
In controller the index looks like

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->view('auth/login');
```

and this is the view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>LOGIN
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</h1>
    <?php echo form_open('login/verifylogin'); ?>
    <div class="" style="margin:0">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <div class="" style="display:inline-block;margin:0">
            <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'username','class'=>'','placeholder'=>'Your username here','value'=>set_value('username')]); ?>
        </div>
            <?php echo form_error('username',"<div class='w3-text-red' style='display:inline-block'>","</div>"); ?>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="">
        <?php echo form_label('Password:','pass'); ?>
        <div class="" style="display:inline-block;margin:0">
            <?php echo form_password(['name'=>'password','class'=>'','placeholder'=>'Your password here']); ?>
        </div>
            <?php echo form_error('password',"<div class='w3-text-red' style='display:inline-block'>","</div>"); ?>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Login'); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When a user is successfully validated he is redirected to dashboard view but in address bar still I get `http://192.168.1.102/login/verifylogin` (192.168.1.102 is the localhost or specifically its my device address on which server is running). 
Also if a user leaves a field empty then he is showed the view `auth/login` with respective errors but the address bar shows `http://192.168.1.102/login/verifylogin`.

Please guide me how to fix this.

1. I am a beginner in codeigniter (I also have hands on laravel).
2. I have removed the index.php file according to the given guide.
3. I use ubuntu 14.04

EDIT 1:- I don't want to display the method name in address bar if a user fails login
EDIT 2:- Controller:-

```
<?php
/**
 *
 */
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('auth/login');
    }

    public function verifylogin()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');



        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $this->load->helper('url');

            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $this->load->model('Loginmodel');
            if ($this->Loginmodel->login_valid($username, $password)) {
                redirect('dashboard');
            }else {
                $this->load->view('auth/login');
            }
        } else {
            $this->load->view('auth/login');
        }
    }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: What is `$config['base_url']` value set in `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` file?

Comment: I have set the base_url to "http://www.satoshirps.site"

Comment: show us your controller code

Comment: added the controller code in question

Comment: Try it like `http://satoshirps.site/`.

Comment: Check yourself the website is online.But this also doesn't work.